# Zend Framework migration live to localhost

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, database-migration

I am trying to migrate Zend-Framework V 1.10.2 live server to my localhost.

Database connection file : application/configs/application.ini

```
;# Database #
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = 'root'
resources.db.params.password = '123456'
resources.db.params.dbname = 'wisedsongshotdb'
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

I am getting only 1 error

> Error establishing a database connection

any one have idea what's the problem? give me some debug tips too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of lines you can use to get the error details:

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Usually, we do use subsections to set these settings only for development. Your environment is set through the APPLICATION_ENV environment variable (in the virtualhost most of the time).